# Does MySQL execute a query in the order it is written?

Tags: mysql, alias

Does MySQL execute a query in the order it is written?

I notice sometimes the alias (e.g. in the below: customers AS c) is in a line after the alias is used. Usually in other programming you declare a variable first, before using it. But in Mysql I’ve seen things like this:

```
SELECT SUM(balance) AS Total,  
COUNT(account_id) AS Number,   
CONCAT(c.last_name, ', ', c.first_name) AS Name  
FROM accounts AS a   
INNER JOIN customers AS c  
USING (customer_id)  
GROUP BY (a.customer_id) ORDER BY Name;
```

How can ***`CONCAT(c.last_name, ', ', c.first_name)`*** be executed when ***customers AS c*** doesn't occur until the third last line? And it doesn’t result in an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In sql the code is evaluated  in a specific order:

- first the FROM clause is evaluated and the related alias
- then the WHERE condition
- after that the SELECT clause
- and last the GROUP BY, the HAVING clause and the ORDER BY

So the table alias names are perfectly known at the select time.

Comment: ahh yes. im new to stack overflow so didnt realize this. Thanks.

Comment: The answer is not as simple as that. Take the following example: `SELECT date(ts) as dt, count(*) as cnt FROM log GROUP BY dt`.
How can you SELECT `count(*)` before `GROUP BY` but at the same time use the alias `dt` in GROUP BY?
The use of aliases has little to do with the order of evaluation or execution.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is a pretty good one actually.

Think about it this way:
You cannot select anything once you know where to select it from.
In the same way, you can not order anything before it has been selected.

So, when you create an alias on a tablename, mysql can then use that in the selection part.
And when you create a alias in the selection part, mysql can use that in the order part.

I hope this clarifies it for you. Please let me know if this answers it for you.